# WSO2BAM monitoring realtime traffic from rest-API

Tags: rest, events, wso2, wso2-bam

I use WSO2BAM to monitor my application activities. I have configured my event stream (`stream.id = "account-management/1.0.0"`) like [this](https://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/Monitoring+Realtime+Traffic). But when I send my events by [REST-API](https://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/Sending+Events+through+the+REST+API) wso2server tells me that it does not find my stream definition.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No stream definitions exist for account_management 1.0.0
```

When I list all events in Main/Manage/Event Processor/Event streams, I can see it. 
When I query the cassandra Cluster/META_KS:STREAM_DEFINITION, I can see it.

I think that REST-API does not search in the same table or does not search the same record. To check if it is the case, I try to send the same event stream definition by the REST-API and the server says that it already exists.

```
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.exception.DifferentStreamDefinitionAlreadyDefinedException: Another Stream with same name and version exist :{"streamId":"account_management:1.0.0","name":"account_management","version":"1.0.0" ...}
```

I try to send a new version of this event stream definition by the REST service, the server accepts but I can not see it in the Main/Manage/Event Processor/Event streams.

Does anyone try to send events by REST-API and configure event stream by carbon server webapp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I stopped searching in this way. I try to use elasticsearch REST API for posting events and kibana for presenting the results. It works like a charm and it's simple! Just enough for me.